# Inject Javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

*Is it possible to autorun any script, for example from scratchpad in Firefox?*
I want to add one button to website without making an extension, because I don't need to use XUL and Rtf.
Maybe can I make add-up, containing only JS file?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ "Greasemonkey"). It allows you to add a javascript file to any page.

Comment: No, I don't want to use any extensions, because my target is writing something like this. Sorry for my English

Comment: So you want to create a full addon, but in Javascript? Perhaps you are looking for the add-on SDK: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK

Comment: Please clarify what you want. Do you want to make a Firefox addon(=extension) or not? Because in the comments you said "my target is writing something like [Greasemonkey]"

Answer (score -1):

If you use Python, then you may use Selenium to mimic person clicking in browser by writing python script.

Besides, Python mechanize is also a good module to automatically do something related to website.

Comment: He does not want to click a button, he wants to add a button to the website.